# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'.ts(2721)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a component with useLayoutEffect but when I add `ref.current?.onselect()` it gives me these errors:

```
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'.ts(2721)
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
lib.dom.d.ts(6026, 44): An argument for 'ev' was not provided.
```

Here is my code:

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { Column } from '../typings'

const Component = ({ focus, onChange, value }) => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLSelectElement>(null)

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if (focus) {
            ref.current?.onselect()
        } else {
            ref.current?.blur()
        }
    }, [focus])

    return (
        <select
            className='dsg-input'
            ref={ref}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value || null)}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can use optional chaining here? With `ref.current?` you imply that this can be `null` or `undefined` and `null|undefined.onselect()` will obviously not work

Comment: I also create a component for `input` type. I used `<HTMLInputElement>` for that. It worked with `ref.current?.select()`.

Comment: @empiric That isn't quite how optional chaining works... if the current value of the ref is `null` or `undefined` then JS bails on processing the rest of the expression, it won't try to access further into the object.. The issue is that `onselect` or `blur` may potentially be undefined, and thus, not invokable.

Comment: @DrewReese oh than I misinerpreted the error message in combination with typescript. I thought that was an error coming up from parsing the TS inspite of the optional chaining

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  if (focus) {
    ref.current?.onselect?.();
  } else {
    ref.current?.blur?.();
  }
}, [focus]);
```

if you're config gives you error about the above code add some check instead:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  if (focus) {
    (typeof ref.current?.onselect === 'function') && ref.current.onselect();
  } else {
    (typeof ref.current?.blur === 'function') && ref.current.blur();
  }
}, [focus]);
```

you can read more about `Optional Chaining` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining